# verilog errors (13069) and (13205). Happens when using `define

Tags: verilog

[These are the errors I keep getting][1]
I cant seen to figure out what is causing these errors I have looked them up several times but I have not found a clear solution. I am not sure what is wrong with my define statement and why I am told I am missing a "X:X". I thought that I had already declared the reg which_seven properly. Thank you for looking at my post.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/orCVx.png

```
`define Ka = 7'b1111000 // seven
`define Kb = 7'b0000000 // eight
`define Kc = 7'b1111001 // one
`define Kd = 7'b0100100 // two
`define Ke = 7'b0110000 // three
`define first = 2'b00 // first seven
`define second = 2'b01 // second seven
module lab4_top(SW,KEY,HEX0);
  input [9:0] SW;
  input [3:0] KEY;
  output [6:0] HEX0;

reg[6:0] present_state;
reg [1:0] which_seven;

always @(KEY == 4'b0000) begin
    if (KEY == 4'b0010 || KEY == 4'b0011)
    present_state = 7'b1111000; 
    which_seven = `first;
    end
else begin 

    case(present_state)
    `Ka: if (SW == 9'b000000000) begin
            if(which_seven == `first) begin
            present_state = `Ka; // if present_state is 7
            which_seven = `second;
            end
        else
            present_state = `Kb;
        
         else begin

            if(which_seven == `first) begin
            present_state = `Ke;
            end

        else begin
            present_state = `Ka;
            which_seven = `second;
            end
        end
          end


    `Kb: if (SW == 9'b000000000) 
            present_state = `Kc; // if present_state is 8

        else 
            present_state = `Ka;


    `Kc: if (SW == 9'b000000000) 
            present_state = `Kd; // if present_state is 1

        else 
            present_state = `Kb;


    `Kd: if (SW == 9'b000000000) 
            present_state = `Ke; // if present_state is 2

        else 
            present_state = `Kc;


    `Ke: if (SW == 9'b000000000) begin
            present_state = `Ka; // if present_state is 3
            which_seven = `first;
            end
        else 
            present_state = `Kd;

    default: present_state = 7'bXXXXXXX;
    endcase

    case(present_state)
    `Ka: HEX0 = 7'b1111000; // seven
    `Kb: HEX0 = 7'b0000000; // eight
    `Kc: HEX0 = 7'b1111001; // one
    `Kd: HEX0 = 7'b0100100; // two
    `Ke: HEX0 = 7'b0110000; // three
    default: HEX0 = 7'bXXXXXXX;
    endcase
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: Don't post images of text.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Should I just copy and paste the text?

Comment: Post your [minimal, reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check your logic. Just find some errors here.

1. When you use `` `define ``, don't add the equal sign `=`. (`=` is needed in `parameter` statement)

   Modify it to :

```
`define Ka  7'b1111000 // seven
```

2. `HEX0` is used in a `always` block, so it should be declared as `reg`.

```
reg [6:0] HEX0;
```

3. The `always @(KEY == 4'b0000)` statement is wrong.

   To save your life, just use the following easier way.

```
always@(*)
```

4. The `if-else` and `begin-end` is no paired in the `always` block.

   Only you know the logic. So check and correct them. Sometimes maintaining a good code indent will help you a lot.
5. `SW` is declared as a 10-bit signal, but is compared with a 9-bit zero. It's ok, but any lint tool will throw a warning message.